# How to execute middle portion of a soap request multiple times using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a soap request (XML) that I am supposed to run with the JMeter tool. The problem here is I want to run the XML in parts, like the first part should execute only once and then the middle part should run n number of times and again the last part should run only once. Is it possible? My XML consists of 50 lines and I want to run lines 30 to 45 multiple times and the rest should execute only once.

Comment: How server will accept only part of XML?

Comment: It won't but we need to figure out a way to make that happen? Like insert 100 times of those lines in between the xml and then execute it